# SharePoint 2010 SPWeb.GetFile() returns SPFile with incorrect version information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a document in SharePoint 2010 that has 3 versions -- 0.1, 1.0 and 1.1.
I need to retrieve version information for file identified by guid. So I call SPWeb.GetFile(guid) that returns SPFile.

When I try to retrieve version information through SPFile.Versions collection, URLs for versions are as follows:

0.1 -- _vti_history/1/Shared Documents/TESTDOC.txt
1.0 -- Shared Documents/TESTDOC.txt
1.1 -- Shared Documents/TESTDOC.txt

when I examine Version History through web I get:

0.1 -- _vti_history/1/Shared%20Documents/TESTDOC.txt
1.0 -- _vti_history/512/Shared%20Documents/TESTDOC.txt
1.1 -- Shared%20Documents/TESTDOC.txt

As you can see URL for version 1.0 is different. Am I dealing with SharePoint bug here or I am doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

when u check in as major version u getting document url somerhing with following

```
version * 512
```

so put some logic in your code and generate url with this equation

Comment: It's a hack. I want to get this info through API.